# Stop character repetition in TextField without NumberFormatter

Tags: swiftui

For example in a textfield I want to be able to repeat all numbers, but user should be able to use decimal point only once. So, the user should not be able to do: "12...4" but should only be able to do it once "12.4". Any particular way to do do it? Is it possible to do it with SwiftUI without using UIKit?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TipsView: View {
    @State private var amount = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Amount")) {
                    HStack (spacing: 1) {
                        Text("£")
                        TextField("Amount", text: $amount)
                            .onReceive(Just(amount)) { _ in
                                
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see expected behaviour in your cases (including posted before) it is more preferable to step back and do all of them with UITextField+Delegate and just wrap result  in UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: Sounds fair, thank you

Comment: refer this answer for iOS17 https://stackoverflow.com/a/77637146/4718413

Answer (score 2):

I have used a String separator to separate the input string into two different arrays. Meaning, one array would contain values before the decimal point and the other would contain values after the decimal point.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DecimalView: View {
    @State private var amount = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Amount")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("£")
                    TextField("Enter amount", text: $amount)
                        .onChange(of: amount) { _ in
                            let filtered = amount.filter {"0123456789.".contains($0)}
                            
                            if filtered.contains(".") {
                                let splitted = filtered.split(separator: ".")
                                if splitted.count >= 2 {
                                    let preDecimal = String(splitted[0])
                                    let afterDecimal = String(splitted[1])
                                    amount = "\(preDecimal).\(afterDecimal)"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small edit. If you use `let splitted = filtered.split(separator: ".", omittingEmptySubsequences: false)` you can avoid multiple simultaneous decimal points.