# TextField that accepts only numbers and one decimal point in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, double, decimal, number-formatting

I searched for a good approach for this problem and none of the questions I'v found answered my needs. I'm struggling with this.

What I need is a `TextField` that would accept only `0123456789.` with format of `%.2f` and wouldn't require to press Return key to submit. Receiving the value as `Double` and return as `Double`.

The results should be `123.45` or `1.23`.

My attempt:

```
    var title: String
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    @Binding var value: Double
    
    var amountProxy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: { String(format: "%.2f", value) },
            set: {
                if let value = numberFormatter.number(from: $0) {
                    self.value = value.doubleValue
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack(spacing: 8){
            Text(LocalizedStringKey(title + ":"))
                .layoutPriority(1)
            TextField(LocalizedStringKey(""), text: amountProxy)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
    }
```

This method results were forcing the user to type one number and move precisely after the decimal point to get the requested value `4.20`. Something like type, move, repeat. Very poor UX.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63906742/12240655 This does most of what you want... modify it to match your requirements

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed to convert it back to double and that made the trick. for now I didn't found any problem with this approach at seems to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS17 you can use the following:

```
.onChange(of: text, { oldValue, newValue in
    if newValue != "" && Double(newValue) == nil {
        text = oldValue
    }
})
```